# auto update many to many field

Tags: python, django, django-models

i have following database model

```
class Author(models.Model):
    choices=['Mr.','Mrs.','Er.','Dr','Prof',]
    name=models.CharField('Authors Name',max_length=50)
    dob=models.DateField('Birth Date',null=True)
    addr=models.CharField('Address',max_length=100,null=True)
    email=models.EmailField('Email',null=True)
    salutation=models.CharField('Salutation',max_length=4)
    headshot=models.ImageField(upload_to='authors/',null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors=models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher=models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date=models.DateField()
    pages=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    price=models.FloatField()
    cover=models.ImageField(upload_to='books/',null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The Book, Author and Publisher objects will be created from django administration. For every Book object created and selected an Author from authors list the books attribute of Author should be  automatically updated with book that are contributed by that author. i.e if there are authors named Ram, Shyam, Hari and if new book object is created with authors Shyam and Hari and another with Shyam and Ram. The requirement is that books field of Shyam should be automatically updated with Two Book objects.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your models are wrong and you should not do it like this.

Many-to-many fields are already two-way. You should only define the field itself on one side; it doesn't matter which one you put it on, either Book or Author, but choose one only. With that change, when you add the item to one side of the relationship it will automatically be visible on the other.

Comment: i got it and i have edited my question. author.book_set.all() gives all the book set. Thanks